# Concurrency with TPL in .NET. Parallel Generator blocks after a while and gets stuck

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I'm running a game over on CodeGolf.stackexchange.com where players submit bots to compete against one another in the game.

At this stage there's 70 bots and with (N*(N+1))/2 games the tournament is getting quite slow to run so now I'm looking to parallelize it. One of the game rules is that a bot can write to it's own data directory so I want to ensure I don't have a bot instance playing 2 games at once.

I've written an `IEnuemable<T>` generator to yield back valid matches (valid being where neither of the players are currently involved in another match) but I've got some sort of concurrency/blocking problem which causes the Enumerable loop infinitely.

At some arbitrary point, the `while(any matches)` call will just keep looping because the only remaining matches involve players who are in the `activePlayers`  list, so it'll just keep going round and round. This would insinuate that there are active matches in progress.

But the `IsCompleted` event will never be called again so either whatever matches that are running are somehow blocked, or they've completed, but I've got a concurrency bug in the `_activePlayers.TryRemove()` code.

```
public interface IMatchGenerator
{
    void CompleteMatch(Match match);
}

public class MatchGenerator : IMatchGenerator
{
    private static object SYNC_LOCK = new object();
    private ConcurrentDictionary<Player, Player> _activePlayers; //tracks players actively playing
    private ConcurrentQueue<Match> _allMatches;

    public MatchGenerator()
    {
        _activePlayers = new ConcurrentDictionary<Player, Player>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Match> Generate(IList<Match> matches)
    {
        //take the list of matches passed in and stick them in a queue.
        _allMatches = new ConcurrentQueue<Match>(matches);

        //keep looping while there are matches to play
        while (_allMatches.Any())
        {
            Match nextMatch;

            lock (SYNC_LOCK)
            {
                 _allMatches.TryDequeue(out nextMatch); //Grab from front of queue

                if (!_activePlayers.ContainsKey(nextMatch.Player1) &&
                     !_activePlayers.ContainsKey(nextMatch.Player2))
                {
                    //If neither player is in the active player list, then this is a
                    //good match so add both players
                    _activePlayers.TryAdd(nextMatch.Player1, nextMatch.Player1);
                    _activePlayers.TryAdd(nextMatch.Player2, nextMatch.Player2);

                }
                else
                {
                    //Otherwise push this match back in to the start of the queue...
                    //FIFO should move on to next;
                    _allMatches.Enqueue(nextMatch);
                    nextMatch = null;
                }
            }
            if (nextMatch != null)
                yield return nextMatch;
        }
    }

    public void CompleteMatch(Match match)
    {
        //Matches in progress have the generator attached to them and will call 
        //home when they are complete to remove players from the active list
        Player junk1, junk2;
        lock (SYNC_LOCK)
        {
            _activePlayers.TryRemove(match.Player1, out junk1);
            _activePlayers.TryRemove(match.Player2, out junk2);
        }
        if (junk1 == null || junk2 == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Uhoh! a match came in for completion but on of the players who should have been in the active list didn't get removed");
        }
    }
}
```

And the code which is using this.

```
var mg = new MatchGenerator();
//Code to generate IList<Match> or all player combinations and attach mg

Parallel.ForEach(mg.Generate(matches),
                    new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8},
                    match =>
                    {
                        var localMatch = match;
                        try
                        {
                            PlayMatch(localMatch, gameLogDirectory, results);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            localMatch.IsCompleted();
                        }
                    });
```

From here it gets a little verbose but there's not an awful lot going on.
`PlayMatch(...)` calls a method call `Play` and has some stringbuilder code in it.
`Plays` calls a couple of external processes depending on the bot that's playing (i.e. ruby/python etc... It also StreamWrites to a per player log file but assuming that only one player bot is in action at a time, there should be any clashes here.

The whole Control program is available on GitHub @

https://github.com/eoincampbell/big-bang-game/blob/master/BigBang.Orchestrator/Program.cs

```
    public static Result Play(Player p1, Player p2, string gameLogDirectory)
    {
        var dir = Player.PlayerDirectory;

        var result = new Result() { P1 = p1, P2 = p2, P1Score = 0, P2Score = 0 };
        string player1ParamList = string.Empty, player2ParamList = string.Empty;
        List<long> p1Times = new List<long>(), p2Times = new List<long>();
        Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch(), sw2 = new Stopwatch(), swGame = new Stopwatch();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                UseShellExecute = false, RedirectStandardOutput = true, WorkingDirectory = dir
            }
        };

        swGame.Start();
        sb.AppendLine("+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+");
        sb.AppendFormat("| Starting Game between {0} & {1} \n", p1.Name, p2.Name);
        sb.AppendLine("| ");
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            sw1.Reset();
            sw1.Start();
            var o1 = ProcessRunner.RunPlayerProcess(ref proc, player1ParamList, player2ParamList, p1, dir);
            sw1.Stop();
            p1Times.Add(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);

            sw2.Reset();
            sw2.Start();
            var o2 = ProcessRunner.RunPlayerProcess(ref proc, player2ParamList, player1ParamList, p2, dir);
            sw2.Stop();
            p2Times.Add(sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds);


            var whoWon = GetWinner(o1, o2, ref player1ParamList, ref player2ParamList);
            var whoWonMessage = "Draw Match";
            if (whoWon == "P1")
            {
                result.P1Score++;
                whoWonMessage = string.Format("{0} wins", p1.Name);
            }
            else if (whoWon == "P2")
            {
                result.P2Score++;
                whoWonMessage = string.Format("{0} wins", p2.Name);
            }

            sb.AppendFormat("| {0} plays {1} | {2} plays {3} | {4}\n", p1.Name, o1, p2.Name, o2, whoWonMessage);

        }
        swGame.Stop();
        sb.AppendLine("| ");
        sb.AppendFormat("| Game Time: {0}", swGame.Elapsed);

        result.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        var resultMessage = string.Format("Result: {0} vs {1}: {2} - {3}",
                        result.P1,
                        result.P2,
                        result.P1Score,
                        result.P2Score);

        sb.AppendLine("| ");
        sb.AppendFormat("| {0}", resultMessage);



        using (var p1sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(gameLogDirectory, p1.Name + ".log"), true))
        {
            p1sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
        using (var p2sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(gameLogDirectory, p2.Name + ".log"), true))
        {
            p2sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }

        result.P1AvgTimeMs = p1Times.Average();
        result.P2AvgTimeMs = p2Times.Average();

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for `PlayMatch`?

Comment: Will update in Question.

Comment: Does your `Process` object wait until it terminates?

Comment: yep. Start. ReadSTDOOUT. Exit. All processes being exec'd have been tested outside of this as well and none of them block on exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your problem is caused by the use of `Parallel.ForEach()` on a `IEnumerable<T>` that may take indefinitely long to produce the next element. This is basically the same issue as [using `Parallel.ForEach()` on `BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx):

> the partitioning algorithm employed by default by both Parallel.ForEach and PLINQ use chunking in order to minimize synchronization costs: rather than taking the lock once per element, it'll take the lock, grab a group of elements (a chunk), and then release the lock.

But since in your case, the next element in the sequence won't be produced until a previous element is processed, this will cause indefinite blocking.

I think the right solution here is to use `BlockingCollection<T>` instead of `yield return`: replace `yield return nextMatch` with `blockingCollection.Add(nextMatch)`, then run `Generate()` on a separate thread and use `blockingCollection.GetConsumingPartitioner()` from the blog post mentioned above in the `Parallel.ForEach()`.

I also don't like that your `Generate()` wastes a whole CPU core basically doing nothing when there are no valid matches, but that's a separate issue.